# Run postman tests on Bamboo

Tags: bamboo, bitbucket-server, postman-collection-runner

I have tests setup on my postman Endpoints and are all in a collection , However I would like to run this collection on a Bamboo server and run it at intervals. Please assist in a walkthough of how to set it up.

I have stored the collection on bitbucket and would like to read the collection from there